# Odd or even function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show whether the function f  is odd , even or other wise 
Where $$f(x) = 2 , x\in ]0,\infty[ , f(x) =- 2 , x\in ]-\infty , 0]$$
I think that the function is odd because it is symmetric around the origin point , for the value 0 in the domain since -0=0 , f(0) and f(-0) can not be the additive inverse to each other ? Does the answer correct or not

Comment: The function is not even, since $f(x) \not= f(-x)$ for $x > 0$, nor is it odd, since $2 = f(0) \not= -f(0) = -2$ (in fact, odd functions must be equal to $0$ at the origin).

Comment: Neither odd nor even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an odd function, $f(0)=-f(0)$ so that $f(0)=0$ is mandated.

---

Note that the even part of this function is

$$\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}2=\begin{cases}x=0\to-2,\\x\ne 0\to0\end{cases}$$

and the odd part

$$\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}2=\begin{cases}x<0\to-2,\\x=0\to0,\\x>0\to2.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not odd due to the reason that $f(0) \neq - f(0)$ (By definition of an odd function $f(-x) = -f(x) $ is satisfied in every $x$ and $-x$ in the domain) . It is obviously not even either.